# Swift generic structure initialization with handler breaks syntax highlighting

Tags: discussion, bug, syntax-highlighting

I originally filed this report in [highlight.js's GitHub repository](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2758). After reading the comments, I'm not sure if it's auto-detected as Objective-C, if the library used is out of date and there's a fix in a newer version, or if it's a different issue.

The question where I encountered this is [How do you add a CAGradientLayer to a UIBackgroundConfiguration in the new collection views with compositional layouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380964/how-do-you-add-a-cagradientlayer-to-a-uibackgroundconfiguration-in-the-new-colle)

Comment: It is being autodetected as Objective C. To see how a code block is being highlighted, Inspect it in the browser and look at the class. `<pre class="default s-code-block hljs objectivec"` -> `objectivec`. Adding the Swift tag might help. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401573

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a highlighter problem *per say*, it just detected the language wrong. I edited in a language id for swift on the code block to make the highlighting right, if someone wants to approve it.

Comment: While there are definitely improvements that could be made to the language auto-detect, there isn't much syntax in that code block specifically that could be used to say "this is definitely Swift code" (I do say that as a non-expert looking in, however).

Comment: The highlighting also works properly if you tag your question with [swift]. I'm not going to do that since I'm not sure which of the existing tags you might want to get rid of, but generally you should always tag your question with the programming language you're using.