# New code formatting engine has some weirdness

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I am seeing a bit of weirdness with the new code formatting library on this Stack Overflow question:

[Phone Number Regex Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64275568/phone-number-regex-conditions)

Here is how my answer is being formatted:

[image]

As you can see, something is spoofing the JavaScript engine into thinking that it should be doing into Italic mode, inside a code block.  For reference, my answer works (assuming PHP is actually the OP's language), as [this demo](https://rextester.com/UVDXZN23198) shows.

Here are my browser specs (Windows laptop):

```
Chrome Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (32-bit)
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: @WaiHaLee There are no asterisks in my answer.  I have never seen this behavior the entire 8 years I have been using Stack Overflow, hence I posted a question here.

Comment: Late comment: The italics seem to be getting kicked in due to the underscore.  But, that UI feature should be turned off inside a code block, I think.

Comment: This is a PHP question, right? Try adding the PHP tag to the question and see if the formatter behaves better.

Comment: @legoscia Brilliant answer.  Could you post that, assuming there isn't already an exact duplicate?

Comment: The question now is, what is the default behavior for code formatting in absence of an actual programming language.

Comment: It tries to guess the language. If there are only a few lines of code, it seems to guess Markdown more often than it should, where using italics between asterisks and underscores makes sense.

Comment: Can't believe I've never seen this before.  Which also means that generally folks are very good about tagging with their language.

Comment: This is a new problem following [the change to highlight.js](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401031/1364007) in September.

Comment: @legoscia [Current maintainer of Highlight.js here] If someone wants to compile a list of 5-10 examples of "guesses Markdown more than it should" and file a GitHub issue I'd be happy to take a closer look when I have time...